# GCC not found in PATH/Eclipse Configuration issue Eclipse 2019-06 IDE for Windows will not let me run any user input, exit value -1,073,741,819

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc

I work in Eclipse and tried to do some code for a calculator and every time I try to run it it says GCC not found in path and also does not allow any user input. The exit value is -1,073,741,819.

I tried to redownload everything and nothing worked it works fine with a hello world or a program without making the user enter anything such as numbers, etc.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(){

double num1;
double num2;
char op;

printf("Enter a number: ");
scanf("%f", &num1);
printf("Enter the operator: ");
scanf(" %c", op);
printf("Enter second number: ");
scanf("%f", &num2);


if(op == '+'){
    printf("%f", num1 + num2);
} else if(op == '-'){
    printf("%f", num1 - num2);
} else if(op == '*'){
    printf("%f", num1 * num2);
} else if(op == '/'){
    printf("%f", num1 / num2);
} else {
    printf("Invalid Operator");
}

return 0;
```

}

I expect the numbers and operator to pop up but nothing happens, not sure what to do though. Also says

```
gcc -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o main.o "..\\main.c" 
Cannot run program "gcc": Launching failed
```

Error: Program "gcc" not found in PATH and I am positive that gcc is running but says no input files.

Comment: You have a basic gcc/Eclipse configuration problem. The code is irrelevant.

Comment: Ok, thank you Eugene Sh, what may be the solution? Because it works when I do a hello world or just print but never works when I enter code that needs an input that is why I put this in my question. Do you know a solution by any chance?

Comment: If it cannot run gcc then how does gcc manage to say no input files?

Comment: Your title should really be a short summary of the problem you have, and the problem is that the `gcc` front-end program can't be found and not anything about "no input files".

Comment: @immibis I am not sure how because it works for certain code such as only printing and never works with a program with user input. Sometimes it would be a blank console. Do you a solution by any chance?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude well I don't know what you mean by its a front end because when I check the version of it  it states GCC: fatal error: no input files compilation terminated and I still don't know what to do hence the name is like this.

Comment: Except for gcc/Eclipse configuration problem, the code is invalid. The `"%lf"` scanf modifier should be used with `double`, not `"%f"`.

Comment: Ok thank you @KamilCuk, I need to know about the GCC/Eclipse configuration problem, do you know anything about that?

Comment: As of now, you posted nothing about that. Only code and error message. Even searching google with `Program "gcc" not found in PATH` you get many links and other people responses.

Comment: @KamilCuk I understand that, but I tried those for about 27 days and most of them do not work for me that is why I made my own question and am asking for answers, if you the answer please feel free to tell me. All help to me will help me start off my career.

Comment: The error in the *question* doesn't say anything about "no input files". What is the actual error you're really asking about? And please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).